# Wrong type argument in conditional

Tags: arguments

I have the following code that counts the number of opening and closing braces, but getting the error

```
and: Wrong type argument: stringp, 40
```

Here is the code:

```lisp
    (defcustom rk-bracemk '("()" "[]" "{}" "<>")
      "Two-character strings of open and close delimiters."
      :type '(repeat string)
      :group 'convenience)
    
    (defun rk-bracemk-count (brcmarks reg-beg reg-end)
      "Count brace marks within a region.
    
    BRCMARKS  String defining opening and closing brace marks.
    REG-BEG   Marker defining start of region.
    REG-END   Marker defining end of region.
    
    Usage
          M-x rk-bracemk-count"
    
      (interactive
       (list
        (completing-read "Bracemarks: " rk-bracemk nil t)
        (region-beginning)
        (region-end)))
    
      (save-excursion
    
        (let* ( (begmk (aref brcmarks 0))
            (endmk (aref brcmarks 1))
                (a 0) (b 0) )
      
          (goto-char reg-beg)
          (while (and (< (point) reg-end)
                      (search-forward begmk reg-end t))
            (cl-incf a))
    
          (goto-char reg-beg)
          (while (and (< (point) reg-end)
                      (search-forward endmk reg-end t))
            (cl-incf b))
    
          (message "Markers: %c %c" begmk endmk)
          (message "Counts %d %d" a b)
          (goto-char reg-beg)) ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pretty clear -- you're passing the number 40 to something that requires a string.  Use the debugger to see where that's happening:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `toggle-debug-on-error`

Perhaps you think `aref` on a string will return a string?  It returns a character (which is an integer).  40 is `(`.  You probably want `char-to-string`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that OP is passing the char `?\(` (40) as the first arg to `search-forward`, and that arg needs to be a string.

Comment: Done as suggested, solving the problem `(p (aref brcmarks 0))  (q (aref brcmarks 1)) (begmk (char-to-string p))  (endmk (char-to-string q))`